# Maximum stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have this javascript method:

```
function waitcheck(){
        if(wait == 0){
            offlineUpload()
        }
        else{
            setTimeout(waitcheck(), 2000)
        }
    }
```

I'm lost, right now I'm getting an error saying "Maximum stack size exceeded"

The goal of this method is to wait until a var is turned into "0" by an async function.

Is there a better way to do this?
How can I get around this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling the `waitcheck` function recursively, instead of passing the function into `setTimeout`.

Do this in your `else`:

```
setTimeout(waitcheck, 2000)
```

Assuming your `wait` global is set correctly outside of this function, your code should work.

Comment: This is correct.  Completely screwed up my code (no semicolons and () where It shouldn't be).  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the textbook example where to use `setInterval`

This will execute your checker function every 2 seconds and stop when wait is 0.

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  if(wait === 0){
    clearInterval(interval);
    offlineUpload();
  }
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parentheses on the function name. (They're causing that function to be called, instead of passing it as a reference.)

Like so:

```
function waitcheck(){
        if(wait == 0){
            offlineUpload()
        }
        else{
            setTimeout(waitcheck, 2000)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is correct.  Completely screwed up my code (no semicolons and () where It shouldn't be).  Thanks